# Sending the bearer token with axios+ts

Tags: axios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG47u.png)

> Blockquote
> just above picture

Comment: if you can give me idea, i'll preciate for you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Certain questions here are more likely to get helpful answers. Questions that share code as images instead of code blocks usually indicate you haven't read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and people often skip right over them. So share your code as indicated. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, we can help with that, and we want to - that’s part of why we’re here. If you’re really ambitious, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.